# Why can't I "plus 1" certain pages in Google+?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-1

I have a Google+ account and the "g+1" button on my toolbar.

For most web pages the button is enabled and I can, should I so wish, show my "love" for the page by clicking it.

However, there are some pages where the "g+1" button is disabled.

Is this something Google decides or is there a code web developers can include on their pages that disables the button?

Comment: Are these public web pages you don't need any login to get to?

Comment: @EightDays that's something I hadn't considered. I'm fairly sure that the pages are visible whether you're logged in to the site or not. I'll run some tests when I'm back at a PC.

Comment: First guess is that you've already +1'd them. Second guess is that the page isn't accessible by the tool Google uses to get page previews to add to G+ posts.

Comment: If you could share an URL or three, I can see if I have the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Google +1 Button extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-%2B1-button/jgoepmocgafhnchmokaimcmlojpnlkhp?hl=en) disables itself on HTTPS sites that have query params (`?foo=bar`).

> Today, we’ve removed functionality from the button when you visit https sites with query parameters.  This means the +1 button will be grayed out and be unclickable when you visit sites that (a) start with “https://”, and (b) contain the characters “?” or “;” in the URL.
>
> -- [Jonathan McPhie](https://plus.google.com/+jmcphie/posts/YmtuwRwDQ77)

The reason is because some sites grant access to private data based on tokens in the URL and Google doesn't want users to publish those tokens publically.

Comment: That would explain it. Thanks. I was just about to post some examples and see that they do conform to this format.